# Is there a way to convert between a Ref parameter type and the non-ref version in C#

Tags: c#

I'm looking at the parameters of a method and extracting the types.  I get back (for instance) "System.String&", because the parameter is an out parameter.  I want to know whether the parameter is a String - but there doesn't seem to be a way of converting a String& to its non-ref counterpart.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a `ref` parameter on a method and inspect the parameter type using reflection you get the type name with an added ampersand indicating that it is a `ref` parameter.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks, never knew that.

Comment: It's inside the Invoke method of a RealProxy object.  You can see something similar here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype.aspx
The answer beneath is what I was looking for though!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Type.GetElementType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx)

> The Type of the object encompassed or
>   referred to by the current array,
>   pointer, or reference type, or null if
>   the current Type is not an array or a
>   pointer, or is not passed by
>   reference, or represents a generic
>   type or a type parameter in the
>   definition of a generic type or
>   generic method.

Example:

```
var stringRefType = typeof(string).MakeByRefType();
var stringType = stringRefType.GetElementType();
Console.WriteLine(stringType == typeof(string)); // True
```

Comment: And you would use the `IsByRef` property to determine that it is a reference type, instead of checking if the type name ends with a "&", to complete your answer.

Comment: It makes me so happy that answers to obscure questions like this have actually been answered here. SO win!